# How to DOM made select element value from one javascript function to another

Tags: javascript

I want to ask that how can I call the value of select option which i made in the selectInput function and and now i want to call the value of select option value in searchPanel function i made selectInput function return type still i unable to call the value

```
    function searchPanel() {
           const div = document.createElement("div");

           div.appendChild(selectInput());
     }



     function selectInput() {
        const select = document.createElement("select");
        select.className = `form-control form-control-sm mb-3`;
        select.id = "disposal-type";
        select.setAttribute("name", "disposal");

              const option_Case = document.createElement("option");
              option_Case.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Case"));
              option_Case.setAttribute("value", "Case");
              select.appendChild(option_Case);

              const option_Petition = document.createElement("option");
              option_Petition.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Petition"));
              option_Petition.setAttribute("value", "Petition");
              select.appendChild(option_Petition);



       return select;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call the `selectInput()` before `div.appenchild` and store it in a constant and then use it.

```
function searchPanel() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const select = selectInput();
  div.appendChild(select);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectInput` function is returning the select DOM object correctly.

If you want to check the select option values, you may iterate over select options and use `options` array property to access its values.

```
const select = selectInput();

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    var option = select.options[i];
    alert(option.text + " " + option.value);
}
```

**To display it on the screen:**
If you want this select to appear on the screen, you should attach it to the `document` object as follows:

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Also, call the `searchPanel` method in the body tag using `onload` event attribute.

```
<body onload="searchPanel()"></body>
```